# Weblogic 11g, deployed an ear on managed server, not able to access

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ear, atg

I checkout an existing atg project into eclipse, built ear locally and deployed on a weblogic 10.3.6 Server(on a managed server) from weblogic admin console, 
My AdminServer is running, node manager running, Managed server running and deployment on managed server is successful.
But when I try ti access the application from `http://localhost:<Managed_server_listening_port>/<context_root>/resource_name`

I see 500 server error, no other error message in logs or on my eclipse console. Could you please let me know ideas, should I make sure anything on my managed server.(The same project runs well on other server).

Comment: Is your application running inside of Weblogic? If it is, you should be able to access it from http://localhost:<port>/resource_name

Comment: My deployment on managed server was successful and I see it is running(from admin console), http://localhost:7003/root/ or any other resource name giving 500 error[7003 is my managed server listening port]

Answer (score 1):

If you can let us know the exact 500 server error, we can try to troubleshoot. If you can give us still more information, it would help.